# Are events $A$ and $B$ independent?

Tags: probability

The following is the diagram for the problem:[image]

So my working is: $P(A)= 0.30$,  $P(B)= 0.40$

$P(A) P(B) = 0.30 \times 0.40 = 0.12$

$P(A \cap B)= 0.12$

And since, $P(A) P(B) = P(A \cap B)$ events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

The book solution says $P(B) = 0.28$ (it does not include $0.12$) which leads to events not being independent.

Comment: The difference between your solution and the book's solution comes down to different interpretations of a badly ambiguous diagram. In the first place, I don't see how your interpretation is any harder to justify than the book's, and in the second place, it was bad form to have multiple interpretations, one of which leads to a determination of independence!

Comment: FWIW I honestly think OP's interpretation is probably the standard one for Venn Diagrams, i.e., every number refers to the contiguous region in which it lies.  I'm not quite seeing what consistent logic the book would be using to get its answer, so this sounds to me more like a flat out mistake than ambiguity.

Comment: Poorly picked numbers. Is it specified in the book somewhere how such diagrams are read?

Comment: To me, it seems clear (presuning the diagram is from the book, not your's) , that your working is correct, $P(B) = 0.40$

Comment: @MW: I think, upon reflection, that you're right.

Comment: Thank you all. The diagram is from the book